# SharePoint mysite with follow feature

Tags: 2013, performance, mysite

I have a SharePoint site with docs in doc library and i want to create a custom webpart with follow docs feature of SharePoint . so I realized to create a mysite in order to make my webpart working with the docs followed. Question is : I have 300000 users accessing the site . suppose a user logs in for first time and tries to follow a document . will there be any performance issues ? Because once a user tries to follow a document I think a my site is immediately created in back end .  or what is the best approach for these number of users ?